# Recover visual studio files after windows system restore

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, restore

I recovered from a Windows computer crash by using System restore to go back to the last restore point.

I just realized that that also restored all my Visual Studio projects to what they were at the time! WHAT?

Is there a way to recover all the work I did in Visual Studio since the last restore point?

Edit: System restore says: "System Restore does not affect any of your documents, pictures or other personal data, and the process is reversible".

Well, not so: 
1) It's not reversible
2) It does affect one's documents

Aaaarg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Can I undo the changes System Restore makes to my System?
>
> Yes. Every time you use System Restore, a restore point is created before proceeding, so you can undo the changes if they don't fix your problem. If you use System Restore when the computer is in safe mode or using the System Recovery Options, you cannot undo the restore operation. However, you can run System Restore again and choose a different restore point, if one exists.
>
> To undo the changes System Restore makes
>
> 1. Open System Restore by clicking the Start button . In the search box, type System Restore, and then, in the list of results, click System Restore.‌  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> 2. Click Undo System Restore, and then click Next.
> 3. Review your choices, and then click Finish.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/system-restore-faq#1TC=windows-7)</sup>

In the future, setup some kind of source control system GitHub, [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/sign-up-for-visual-studio-online) (It's free for up to 5 users), or even TFS Express on a central server somewhere in your network.

At the very least configure File History to store a historic copy of your files on a separate disk or network location.

Comment: Thanks > If you use System Restore when the computer is in safe mode, you cannot undo the restore operation. ---- Well guess what: it was in safe mode. F**!   > setup some kind of source control system -- I have for most of my work, but I didn't for Visual Studio. I do have off-line back up that is more recent than the restore point, but stil..

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I tend to rely on multiple options. File History is a great life saver, as is a real source control tool like Git,  TFS or VSO.